# Hibernate using JPA (annotated Entities) and liquibase

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, liquibase

liquibase is a perfect alternative to hibernate's **[hbm2ddl_auto](http://www.jroller.com/eyallupu/entry/hibernate_s_hbm2ddl_tool)** property if you are using xml-mapping. But Im using JPA annotation (hibernate annotations). Is it possible to use liquibase then?

Comment: Did you get this working with the annotations?  The Liquibase documentation page referenced below only covers pointing it to an XML file.

Comment: Nathan Voxland created a patched release for me

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, Liquibase uses hibernate's metadata classes, which are the same whether you use xml mappings or annotations.  You do need a hibernate config file to point liquibase to, but your mappings can be xml or jpa annotations. More information can be found at https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-hibernate/wiki but you can use "database urls" such as

```
hibernate:classic:com/example/hibernate.cfg.xml
```

if you have a hibernate xml conf file or

```
hibernate:ejb3:myPersistenceUnit
```

if you have a META-INF/persistence.xml, or

```
hibernate:spring:com.example?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

if you would like auto-generate a JPA configuration based on a java package containing annotated Entities.

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more detailed, or point me to a url

Comment: The liquibase hibernate documentation is at http://www.liquibase.org/manual/hibernate.  Is there anything in particular you are wondering?

Comment: The source should build fine.  Send me an email nathan [at] voxland.net and I can help you out

Comment: The answer is still incomplete. What are the arguments when you don't have a `hibernate.cfg.xml` file?

Comment: @OttoAllmendinger Yes, exactly. In out case we don have `hibernate.cfg.xml` file. Can we still use LiquiBase?

Comment: Currently if you don't have a hibernate.cfg.xml file, liquibase does not know how to read in your current mappings to compare it to the database schema, so you can't use liquibase to automatically generate changeSets based on your hibernate model. You can still definitely use liquibase still, however, by simply manually appending the changes you need to your changeLog. That is normally the approach I would recommend anyway over a diff-based workflow.

Comment: @NathanVoxland, Currently we don't have `hibernate.cfg.xml` which are migrated to Spring Java bean configuration. You've mentioned that hibernate.cfg.xml is needed in your previous answer.. But it's been 4 years since that, So is `hibernate.cfg.xml` still needed if I'm gng to use liquibase (latest version) for schema generation / diff based on Hibernate annotated model classes in a package..?