# Liquibase diffChangeLog against a Hibernate mapping definition

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, liquibase

This question is related to "[Hibernate using JPA (annotated Entities) and liquibase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776787/hibernate-using-jpa-annotated-entities-and-liquibase)".

I was actually wondering what to expect when doing a *Liquibase diff against a Hibernate mapping definition*.

**What it seems to produce:** A liquibase changelog that migrates the state of my hibernate mappings to the current image of the database.

**What I was hoping for:** A liquibase changelog that migrates the existing (old) database to reflect the changes in my (new) hibernate mappings.

Am I expecting the wrong thing? or am I doing something wrong?

Thank you for letting me know! 
J.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer was too obvious...

It was just a matter of flipping the base- and target system :-)

```
 --username=un \
 --password=pw \
 --url=jdbc:mysql:///mydb \
 diffChangeLog \
 --baseUrl="hibernate:/hibernate.hbm.xml"
```

*becomes:*

```
 --url="hibernate:/hibernate.hbm.xml" \
 diffChangeLog \
 --baseUrl=jdbc:mysql:///mydb \
 --baseUsername=un \
 --basePassword=pw
```

Sorry! 
Time for sleep :-)

Comment: In the upcoming liquibase 2.0 version, we changed the naming to be hopefully more obvious than target and base.