# Java JPA, How to do Updates to a table without destroy-create?

Tags: java, jpa, db2, jpa-2.0

I was learning some JPA to teach to some java friends and I was wondering, how do you handle updates that comes after the creation of the db in JPA? Let's say I have a production environment where there's data that I cannot lose.

Some changes comes in and how do I apply that on my production environment? It there a way that JPA would only update the changes on the database?

Or do I need to manually create a SQL script to update my database?

Is there any other options?

[]'s
Rodrigo Dellacqua

Answer (score 0):

> Some changes comes in and how do I apply that on my production environment? It there a way that JPA would only update the changes on the database?

Nothing standardized. In other words, that would be a provider specific feature. For example, Hibernate has a SchemaUpdate tool that can (in theory) safely update a database schema. In practice, [many don't use that on a production database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221379/hibernate-hbm2ddl-autoupdate-in-production) (including me).

> Or do I need to manually create a SQL script to update my database?

Using migration scripts (and maybe a [database migration tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131020/migrations-for-java)) is IMO the safe way to handle this and is the way to go on real life projects.

And again, some migration tools might provide support for a given JPA provider. For example, [liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) does offer [Hibernate support](http://www.liquibase.org/manual/hibernate) and [can diff your Entities against a database to generate a change script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776787/hibernate-using-jpa-annotated-entities-and-liquibase).