# best practice to synchronize database changes with hibernate mapping file

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Assuming an existing application which deals with lets say 20+ tables, needs to be rewritten using `java`/`jpa`/`hibernate` and if all the tables already existed, is it the usual/best practice to use `hibernate reverse engineering` to generate `hibernate mapping files`?

1. and if the table structure gets changed, say added/modifed 10 fields in 3 different tables, do the `mapping files` get edited by hand to reflect the changes in the database?
2. also if its a brand new application (with new tables), is it the usual/best practice to `create` the `database` objects using the `ddl` generated by `hbm2ddl`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blindly using hbm2dll on production database could lead to data loss.

Take a look at specialized database migration tool like [Liquibase or Flyway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8418814/db-migration-tool-liquibase-or-flyway).

See [Hibernate using JPA (annotated Entities) and liquibase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776787/hibernate-using-jpa-annotated-entities-and-liquibase).

Comment: Thanks, `Flyway` looks very interesting, I will look into it. What about generating `hbm` files from existing tables if I am rewriting an existing application? are there any tools for that? or is `hibernate reverse engineering` the only option (other than writing `hbm` files by hand of course)?

Comment: Yes. See http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-generate-code-with-hibernate-tools/.