# Liquibase JPA configuration of the referenceUrl

Tags: java, jpa, liquibase

I am struggling to build the `JPA` annotated classes diff changesets against my database, using **liquibase**.
Still, I am very confused about few things.

I use the following :

```
liquibase.properties

#liquibase.properties
driver:                 org.postgresql.Driver
classpath:              real_path/.m2/repository/org/postgresql/postgresql/9.2-1002-jdbc4/postgresql-9.2-1002-jdbc4.jar
url:                    jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/diquiz
username:               postgres
password:               postgres
referenceUrl:           hibernate:ejb3:diQuiz
referenceUsername:      postgres
referencePassword:      postgres
changeLogFile:          changelog-master.xml
```

and

```
java -jar real_path\liquibase-core-3.0.6.jar diffChangeLog
```

and a normal `persistence.xml` file with standard JPA configuration.

I get an error which says : `Liquibase diffChangeLog Failed: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find database driver: Driver class was not specified and could not be determined from the url (hibernate:ejb3:unit)`

I am confused because the below answer says that we need a `hibernate.cfg.xml` file (even I have `persistence.xml` instead), but then he says that we can use some url's which are defined on wiki page. 
[Hibernate using JPA (annotated Entities) and liquibase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776787/hibernate-using-jpa-annotated-entities-and-liquibase)

Wiki page says that if we need to use JPA, we can choose between three types of URL's.

```
hibernate:ejb3:myPersistenceUnit
hibernate:ejb3:com.example.MyConfigFactory
hibernate:ejb3:myPersistenceUnit?hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
```

So, I choose the first one, and I've set in the liquidbase.properties this as `referenceUrl`.

Also, on the wiki page it is mentioned : (https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-hibernate/wiki)

> If you are using the command line version of Liquibase, you simply
>   have to add the liquibase-hibernate[3|4].jar file to the
>   LIQUIBASE_HOME/lib directory.

I did this too.
Still, doesnt work. Can someone explain me somewhow what am I missing ?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling liquibase with "java -jar". The Class-path line in the jar can't pick up additional jars from the lib directory and so the liquibase-hibernate.jar is not being included in the classpath.

Run liquibase using the sh/bat file included in the liquibase jar: `real_path/liquibase[.bat] diffChangeLog`