# Liquibase generate update script against source code

Tags: java, database, liquibase

On our project we use Liquibase. So far, if we make any changes in our Hibernate Entities, we have to manually write a Liquibase ChangeLog and add it to our change logs.

Is it possible to generate the ChangeLog file, that would contain only the new changes that developer made?

I was thinking about creating some In-Memory DB, which would be created by Hibernate with dataSource.ddl.auto=create option and then run some database diff, described here http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/diff.html, but this looks like clumsy solution to me and I don't want to reinvent a wheel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Hibernate extension for Liquibase https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-hibernate/wiki and according to the doc it does what you want. But I have not used it myself so I am not aware about its limitations etc.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, however I was not able to make it running, the `Driver class was not specified and could not be determined from the url` exception keeps appearing, no matter what I do. Also it seems that project is not well maintained, there are plenty of pretty old bugs https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-hibernate/issues

Comment: for yor issue I think some sugestions are available here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20031317/liquibase-jpa-configuration-of-the-referenceurl But, as I said, I have not used it earlier so there could be some more problems.